# Spring Security Reauthentication with Persistent Logins

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am using Grails Spring Security Core with Persistent Logins. Thus, the login information of a user are stored in my database. My problem is the following case:

A user is logged in and his username will change from x to y. This means I have to reauthenticate the user with:

```
springSecurityService.reauthenticate y

rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, springSecurityService.authentication)
```

In my database the username for the persistent token remains x. How can I set a new entry for a persistent token with the new username y?

Comment: have you tried saving (and possibly flushing) the user with updated username, then reauthenticating? what happens?

Comment: Can you write some sample code for that?

Comment: better yet, can you show the code where you're doing the username change and where you're doing the reauthenticating.

Comment: This is the code above I updated my question. Username change is simple user.username = y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find the existing database entry for the user. This can be done by username. Then you can set a new database entry as a persistent token with rememberMeServices.loginSuccess. Finally, you have to reauthenticate your user.